# Allocated memory for a thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory

Is it possible to fetch memory usage of a thread in windows programmed by C++?
(I know that this is possible for processes with GetProcessMemoryInfo API.)

Comment: how would that work? How do you decide which thread is using any particular chunk of memory? All threads share the same address  space, which means their "memory usage" is all the same

Comment: @Spook did you read the question at all?

Comment: Ok, I missed the thread/process nuance.

Comment: I believe that a thread share the same address space than the process isn't it ?

Comment: Threads don't have address space - it is a process attribute.

Comment: Set all pages to be guard pages, install an exception handler, and write `GetCurrentThreadId()` to a logfile on every fault?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't such a thing because although a thread has some semi-private memory (Thread Local Storage), the bulk of the memory allocated during a thread's run time is part of the process memory space.

A solution to your problem is to override the various allocation functions (e.g. `malloc`) and have each `malloc` register the allocation using the current thread ID. You'll also need an API to query the allocation DB on how much was allocated.

Comment: What happens to buffers that were allocated by thread A and then signaled to thread B?  Thread A allocated it but now has no reference to it, thread B is using it and will deallocate it when done.

Comment: Implementation details... The same functionlity can be extended to `free()`.

Comment: OP: 'Is it possible to fetch memory usage of a thread', not 'memory allocated'.  In any case, many threads' 'memory usage' is mostly stack, whichis, at least partially, allocated before the thread exists and whose current allocation is OS-managed.

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocation from the shared heap is thread agnostic.

Unless you use specific heaps per thread or some other mechanism of accounting the OS has no way of knowing which thread is using what memory since more than one thread may be using the same memory region.
If you do decide to use separate heaps (say 1/thread) on windows using HeapCreate you can then use HeapWalk to enumerate all allocated blocks per heap and sum the total allocated memory per thread.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any windows API that would do it for you. As others have pointed out, heap usage is not specific to a thread and the only thing you can do is to track which thread allocated how much.However, if you are interested only in stack usage, which is specific to each thread then it is straight forward to implement a pair of functions that can be called from within the thread context that will tell you how much stack space is in use at that instant. For this you can save the address of an automatic variable in your thread entry function as the "stack top" into a global thread safe map for later look up (say void SaveCurrentThreadStackTop(void*);) using thread id as key. Then  at the point of use you call an function (say size_t GetCurrentThreadStackUsage(void);) that declares another automatic variable and subtracts it from the "stack top" saved earlier for current thread id. The result may not be accurate to the byte but close enough.

Comment: The argument to CreateThread decides maximum stack size, above may be useful just in case you are running some recursive algorithm and want to keep track of how close you are to triggering a stack overflow exception.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the heap usage for all threads in Windows. These are the steps:

1. Call [GetProcessHeaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-getprocessheaps)(0, nullptr) to get the number of threads.
2. Allocate some memory for number of threads HANDLE array.
3. [GetProcessHeaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-getprocessheaps)(numberOfHeaps, heaps_array)
4. Iterate through all element of the heaps_array
5. With these pointers start a [HeapWalk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapwalk), which will iterate through all the allocted and freed memory blocks giving back a pointer to a [PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-process_heap_entry) structure.

And that's it.